# c#, MVVM Maui atualizar collection de um picker apos inserir novo item da collection em uma janela popup

Tags: c#, popup, mvvm, maui

estou com um problema e nao sei como resolver, tenho uma view model onde tenho uma ObservableCollection,e na view tenho uma pagina com um picker e um botao onde ao ser acionado, abre uma popup, nesta o usuario informa os campos necessarios para cadastrar um novo item.

```
        Medida medida = new Medida();
        medida.Descricao = DescricaoNovaMedida;
        medida.Sigla = SiglaNovaMedida;
        medida.Conversor = Convert.ToDecimal(ConvervorNovaMedida);

        using (var context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            context.Medida.Add(medida);
            context.SaveChanges();               
            


        }
`
```

Até ai tudo certo, o item é adicionado com sucesso, agora preciso que após fechar essa popup, a pagina por traz dela seja informada se algo foi inserido na collection e se sim, atualizar a collection,atualmente estou usando um botao com o método getall que faz o serviço, porem deve existir uma forma mais automática de atualizar.

```
   [RelayCommand]
    internal void GetAll()
    {
        
        using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            
            List<Medida> lista = context.Medida.ToList();


            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                Medidas.Add(item);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [a documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0), Usando a `shell navigation` do .Net MAUI é possível passar parâmetros ao "navegar para trás".

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..?Refresh=true");
```

E a tela anterior é possível acessar o parâmetro usando `QueryProperty`:

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(Refresh), "Refresh")]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public bool Refresh {get; set; }
    
    // ...
}
```

Ou ainda é possível passar uma lista com todos os IDs relevantes, mas a técnica é a mesma.